# Identifying the erroneous promise with unhandledRejection

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await, puppeteer

I have this code:

```
// <-- add event on top of file
process.on("unhandledRejection", (reason, p) => {
        console.error("Unhandled Rejection at: Promise", p, "reason:", reason);
        // browser.close(); // <-- no need to close the browser here
});

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function getPic() {
    try{ // <-- wrap the whole block in try catch
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/*{headless: false}*/);
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 500}); // <-- add await here so it sets viewport after it creates the page


      //await page.goto('https://www.google.com');  //Old way of doing. It doesn't work for some reason...

      page.goto('https://www.google.com/'); // async


      // wait for either of events to trigger
      await Promise.race([
        page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}),
        page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'})
      ]);


      await page.screenshot({path: 'pic.png'});
      await browser.close(); // <-- close browser after everything is done
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}

getPic();
```

And i get this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {
  <rejected> Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (C:\...\pupet test\node_modules\pupp
eteer\lib\NavigatorWatcher.js:71:21)
    at <anonymous> } reason: Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceede
d
    at Promise.then (C:\...\pupet test\node_modules\pupp
eteer\lib\NavigatorWatcher.js:71:21)
    at <anonymous>
```

I read that the 'unhandledRejection' event is emitted whenever a Promise is rejected and no error handler is attached to the promise within a turn of the event loop.

So from this particular error message, i cannot undedrstand what is causing the problem.

So how i can figure out which is the erroneous promise so i can further understand what went wrong and mitigate it?

Comment: `page.goto('https://www.google.com/').catch(error => console.log("this isn't handled by the try catch since you don't await it", error));`

Comment: If `page.goto('https://www.google.com/');` returns a promise and you don't `await` it, its errors won't be handled.

Comment: Ungh that's so annoying - can you post the rest of your stack trace? I think we can do a better job with these stack traces.

Comment: Ah, I just realized - for a nice experience open node with `node yourfile.js --inspect --inspect-brk` and then open the link in the console - that attaches a debugger. In it tag "pause on thrown exceptions" and you'll have the code break where the problem happens.

Comment: @generalhenry Thanks! Since i used your code, this is what i got:
this isn't handled by the try catch since you don't await it Error: Navigation T
imeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (C:\Users\User1\Desktop\fb proj\pupet test\node_modules\pupp
eteer\lib\NavigatorWatcher.js:71:21)
    at <anonymous>

So it was definately it! My old code used await page.goto('https://www.google.com');

Comment: @generalhenry 
But i was advised to use instead:
page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/');
await Promise.race([
        page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}),
        page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'})
        ]);

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks i will try this!!! Here is the original question though with some testing i did, if this is helpful to you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50152127/node-js-and-puppeteer-promises-causing-an-error

Comment: Also opened https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20505

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170320/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-user1584421).

Comment: @generalhenry I decided not to use awai before page.goto() from this link: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1766#issuecomment-357544291

If you search the answer from user ebidel he says explicitly not to use await before page.goto() and instead use this code i typed above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js and puppeteer promises causing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50152127/node-js-and-puppeteer-promises-causing-an-error)